# pdifferent number of coefficients than columns of Trainingsset

Tags: python, machine-learning, logistic-regression

I trained a logistic regression model in python to predicting a binary classification system.

My Training Set X_train has 25 columns, but I only get 20 coefficients.

Why? What could be the reason?